# Android keystore issue : “Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect”

Tags: android, macos, passwords, migration, keystore

when I tried to sign my apk using eclipse export wizard (I'm a Mac user), I got an error "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect".

And I'm running "AndroidKeystoreBrute" now.
But no result yet.

I think my password was right. 
But, what I did recently on my Mac are upgrading OS to Mountain Lion and using migration assistant to my new SSD.

Would it be possible to break keystore file? 
There is no other possibility to affect to my keystore file, I think.

What do you think about this problem?? 
Please, help..

** update :
I solved my problem by recovering my HDD that I have used before. I'm sure migration assistant broke the keystore file.**

Comment: use the same passwork you created while creating keystore file

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that the actual file got corrupted during your upgrade, but use a backup if you have one just to rule this out. That leaves a wrong password, so you might want to try and remember exactly how you entered it when creating the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest build tool in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```